# global name 'inf' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have developed a function that was on its own in a script. I ran that script to place the function in my namespace. The line of code I have that was working fine is:

```
df.my_variable.replace([inf, -inf, nan, NaN], 0, inplace=True)
```

I have now moved this function into `mymodule.py`. I then try to run it:

```
import mymodule as mm
mm.myfun()
```

The line of code to replace `inf`, etc., now throws the following error:

```
global name 'inf' is not defined
```

I'm sure this is a legacy of developing interactively in IPython, but I'm stumped as to how I would define `inf` to make this work.

Comment: try `from numpy impport inf` at the beginning of your module

Comment: Can you add the complete code for myfun()?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
from numpy import inf
```

Answer (score 1):

`inf` is defined in numpys namespace, so if you just

```
from numpy import inf
```

copy a part of the original script you probably forgot to import this from numpy. Pandas internally uses a lot of numpys functionality

Answer (score 1):

No need to tap into numpy, simply:

```
inf = float('inf')
```

Comment: Yes. It's correct. no need to use the inf from NumPy. It's already there.

Answer (score 0):

assume that you have `numpy` imported as `np`, you can replace `inf` by `np.inf`